# Output changes each time the program is run (C pthread, semaphores)

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

Below is the code, with the only the main parts.
Each time the code is run, the output changes, I assume that it is because `thread 1` does not run, but I am stumped on how to fix it.

I am aiming for the `i` value to be added to 10 times in `thread 1` and then decremented 10 times in `thread 2`, but I do not know why this does not happen on each run through.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int i = 0;
int temp = 0;
sem_t delayT;
sem_t sync;

void * thread1(void * p)
{
    sem_wait(&delayT);
    while(i>0)
    {
        sem_wait(&sync);
        i--;
        temp = i;
        printf("Out:%d\n",i);
        sem_post(&sync);
        if(temp==0)
            sem_wait(&delayT);
    }
}



void * thread2(void * p)
{
    while(i<10)
    {
        sem_wait(&sync);
        i++; 
        printf("in:%d\n",i);
        if(i==10)
            sem_post(&delayT);
        sem_post(&sync);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;

    sem_init(&delayT,0,0);
    sem_init(&sync,0,1);

    pthread_create (&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create (&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);

    pthread_join (t2, NULL);
}
```

Comment: The posted code causes the compiler (gcc) to output several messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create (&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);` and `pthread_create (&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);`   Always check the returned value from C library functions to catch any errors

Comment: these thread functions should be terminated via a call to: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're missing a pthread_join.
you wait for the producer thread but not the consumer then the program stop before thread 1 reach the end of its countdown.

Add

```
 pthread_join(t1, NULL);
```

at the end

Answer (score 0):

regarding: *for the i value to be added to 10 times in thread 1 and then decremented 10 times in thread 2,*

the `i` value is NOT being added to in thread 1.

the `i` value is NOT being decremented in thread 2.

So, either the posted code is wrong or the description of the problem is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition.   In Thread 2:

```
if(i==10)
    sem_post(&delayT);
sem_post(&sync);
```

After posting delayT, it is possible for T1 to advance; then after T2 posts sync, T1 can advance further, so that by the time T2 tests its while condition, i is less than 10. You can disentangle it further to see the valid set of outputs, but I am sure there are a lot.

Simply moving the sem_post(&delayT) outside of the loop should fix this; but you might want to consider some other approaches to this style of problem.